# Rotating object with Matrix.rotate in snap.svg morphs the object

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, snap.svg

I'm trying to use snap.svg library to rotate and move my object but I am getting this weird behavior where the object gets morphed.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOwRga

```
var s = Snap.select("#svg");
var rect1 = s.select("#rect1");
var rect2 = s.select("#rect2");
var rotateMatrix = new Snap.Matrix();
rotateMatrix.rotate(180,302,495);

this.spin = function() {
 rect1.animate({transform:'r180,302,160'},5000,function(){
  rect1.animate({transform:'r0,302,160'},5000);
 });

 rect2.animate({transform: rotateMatrix},5000,function(){
  rect2.animate({transform: rotateMatrix.invert},5000);
 });
}
```

So here I'm rotating two different rectangles. First one works fine and the second one is where i try to use matrix.
What am I doing wrong? Why is this happening? what is the meaning of life?

Comment: You can't really animate a matrix like that. Whats wrong with the first version/rect animation ? Meaning of life is 42.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the first one. I'm just wondering what am i actually doing with the matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one, you are animating a rotation.  Snap knows it is a rotation because of the way you have defined it with Snap's special 'r' initialiser.

In the second one you are just passing a matrix that describes a transform from one orientation to another.  Snap, and the browser, have no idea that it represents a rotation.  So all it is doing is interpolating the values in the matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it helped.

Comment: This also explains my problems with rotations. But even when I use the special 'r' initialiser Snap is setting the transform as a matrix and it doesn't look like a rotation. Any advice how to force Snap to set it as a rotate?

Comment: @daign You should make a new question.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I already got it working like in the codepen by using an older version of Snap. Looks like there is a bug in the current version.